# React-Router render : Functions are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

1. I have created a HOC "ProtectedRoute" to restrict paths for unauthenticated users. I have used "react-router-dom" for routing in the application.
2. I am able to route the users based on their token but I am receiving a warning in the console and I am unable to access routerprops such as "history", "location", "match" in rendered component. Below is the ProtectedRoute component implementation.

   ```
   const ProtectedRoute = ({component:Component, ...rest}) => {
       const [isLoggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState({loggedIn:false, loaded:false})
       useEffect(async () => {
           const userStatus = await validateUserLoggedIn();  # returns true if user is authenticated
           setLoggedIn((prevState) => {return {loggedIn:userStatus, loaded:true}})
       }, [])

       return(
           <Route {...rest} render={(routerProps) => {
               return isLoggedIn.loaded ?
               isLoggedIn.loggedIn ? <Component {...routerProps} {...rest} /> : <Redirect to={{pathname:'/login'}} :
               <h1>Loading Page</h1>
           }} />
       )
   }
   ```
3. ProtectedRoute in main routing component:

   ```
   <Switch>
       <ProtectedRoute exact path="/admin" component={Admin} />
   </Switch>
   ```
4. Error Message "Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it".

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there a few things wrong.

1. You should not return something inside a component, you are doing this inside your `<Route />` component. This is causing the warning: `Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of from render`.
2. Your `<Redirect />` component was missing a `/>` at the end of it, leaving it open will cause an error.

These fixes should also solve your problem where you couldn't access the route props.

```
    <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(routerProps) => {
      isLoggedIn.loaded ? (
        isLoggedIn.loggedIn ? (
          <Component {...routerProps} {...rest} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login' }} />
        )
      ) : (
        <h1>Loading Page</h1>
      );
    }}
  />;
```